# Can't insert into CLOB, Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

*Having lots of trouble with Oracle today.*

I'm trying to insert large strings into CLOB field, getting `ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column`.

But... it's already a CLOB, why is it telling me to use LONG?

**Table definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE crawler (
        ID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        TITLE CLOB NOT NULL ENABLE,
        URL VARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        BODY CLOB NOT NULL ENABLE,
        DEPTH NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE,
        UPDATED NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        LINKED_FROM CLOB NOT NULL ENABLE,
        CRAWLED NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE,
        CONSTRAINT crawler_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT crawler_uni UNIQUE (url)
    );
```

**Statement in Question:**

```
UPDATE sindex SET title = :title, body = :body, depth = :depth, updated = :updated, linked_from = :linked_from, crawled = :crawled WHERE url = :url
```

**Bound: (via PHP's `var_dump()`)**

```
array
  ':url' => string 'https://rockwell.ourtownamerica.com/' (length=36)
  ':title' => string 'Unknown Title' (length=13)
  ':body' => string 'Intranet | Our Town America Marketing Business/Order Forms Direct Mail Download Logos E-Mail Marketing Graphics Clipart Graphic Forms Graphics Samples Our Town Web Store Proofs Sales Dashboard Sales & Marketing Tools Sales Report Testimonials Vendor Portal Sites You Tube Information Current Unordered Zips Deadlines Extra Names Available EDDM Quote Graphics Status Historical Name Search Invoice Inserts Latest News Maps Console Media Archive National Survey Results Offer Research Current vs Proven Offer My Be'... (length=4509)
  ':depth' => string '0' (length=1)
  ':updated' => int 1459969041
  ':linked_from' => null
  ':crawled' => int 1
```

How can this be done? Also, I will need to search on this column as well, so maybe CLOB isn't the right type, but it's the largest AFAIK and it still can't hold my string..

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1461 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01461:
>   can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column 
>   (/core-php-src-5.2.5/php-5.2.5/ext/pdo_oci/oci_statement.c:146)

**Is Oracle capable of handling my data in a way that I will be able to search on it later? If so, how?**

Comment: Maybe Oracle is not the right DB... You should Google on object database

Comment: Oracle is all that's available for this project. Save for the filesystem..

Comment: well Oracle stores data on in files too :p you have an Oracle FS if you want. Oracle DBfs !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly insert blob like common types. You have to bind file descriptor or stream descriptor.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php

For casting you can use utl_raw package in your select : utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2.

But it's limited to the varchar2 max length.

Comment: So basically, I'm going to have to store my blobs in a file either way, right?

Comment: No you have to open a descriptor file, stream or memory

Comment: But is my understanding that you cannot search on a *LOB column correct?

Comment: You have to install some specific package. I ve done it some years ago with a fulltext indexing package from Oracle